# Guess the song and artist (3)

Tags: music

*Enough of the maths clues (well partially!) - something more literary:*

Romulus and Remus; Mowgli.

> **Hint 1:**  Graphics[{Circle[], Line@# & /@ {{{0, -1}, {0, -3}}, {{-1, -2}, {1, -2}}}}]
>  **Hint 2:** Previous answer partial answer to this Q.
>  **Hint 3:** *Hint 1* is song title (one word).

Comment: any more clues?

Comment: @question_asker just added :)

Comment: Updated my guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

> *Woman* by Wolfmother (Female symbol, Romulus and Remus and Mowgli were raised in the wild ('by wolves'))

Comment: that's the one!

Comment: Dear Puzzling.SE, please upvote this answer and stop upvoting mine.

Comment: @JTL the not-really-irony-but-close-enough is that I'm one of the upvotes on yours

Comment: @question_asker Hahah, I knew it.

Answer (score 4):

An incorrect answer is:

> "Raised by Wolves" by U2

My best explanation is that

> Rome's legendary founders and Mowglie are "2" who were "raised by wolves."

I'm spending more time trying to figure out what the first clue is trying to tell us than I am with the puzzle itself.

Comment: nearly - missing link link to previos Q & _MMA_ (sorry!) graphic as song title ...

Comment: @martin That is good; I was hoping that there was something more to this.  I think I'm drawing the graphic incorrectly; the syntax is foreign to me.

Comment: The graphic is a Venus/female symbol: a circle with a line extending below it and another line crossing that.

Comment: @Zandar I initially ignored the order of the coordinates and I couldn't figure out whether or not to put the circle at the origin.